# MVC 5 Model Child list can't render in Partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to `ASP.NET MVC 5`. 
On debug mode, I saw some values being looped to the partial view but in UI no values are being displayed.

My Model

```
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public List<ReferenceModel> ReferenceModelList{ get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult GetModel(string dataobject, int id = 0)
{
    Model model = new Model();
    model = BL.GetModel(dataobject, id);
    return PartialView("_ReferenceModelList", model);
}
```

ReferenceModelList(PartialView)

```
@model Web.Model.Model
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach (var menurefitem in Model.ReferenceModelList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => menurefitem.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => menurefitem.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Partial View Data in VS:
[image]

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the view where you called the partial view

Comment: BL.GetModel what is this method doing ? show the code

Comment: I am calling my partial view via this code             @Html.Partial("_ReferenceModelList",Model) by default it is none and then on dropdown changed i am calling ActionResult GetModel.

Comment: btw i updated the question with picture even though partial view has data it is not rendered in my table.

Comment: Can you call the controller method like this @{Html.RenderAction("GetModel","SAPSecurity");}

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Controller` method from you main UI like this

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetModel","SAPSecurity");}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should instantiate your list at the constructor of your class.I think your problem should be solved.

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        ReferenceModelList=new List<ReferenceModel>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public List<ReferenceModel> ReferenceModelList { get; set; }
}
```